# Write FFMPEG frame to png/jpeg file

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P AVFrame, and I want to write it as PNG or JPEG file, it doesn't matter what format is inside (BGR, BGRA, RGB or RGBA). I tried to save it as AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, but I got 3 pictures in one, so I need to convert it to RGB24 first. I do it via:

```
        int destW = decCtx->width;
        int destH = decCtx->height;

        AVFrame * resFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        resFrame->linesize[0] = destW * 3;
        resFrame->data[0] = (uint8_t*)malloc(resFrame->linesize[0] * destH);

        SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(decCtx->width,
                                          decCtx->height,
                                          AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                          decCtx->width,
                                          decCtx->height,
                                          AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                          SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0);
        sws_scale(ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0,
                  decCtx->height, resFrame->data, resFrame->linesize);
        sws_freeContext(ctx);
        int64_t pts = frame->pts;

        resFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        resFrame->pts = pts;
```

It looks like I have correct converted frame, but now encoder return me a packet with size 86, so my image is actually blank or near it. I do encoding via:

```
    encCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PNG);

    if (!encCodec) {
        return false;
    }

    encCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encCodec);
    if (!encCtx) {
        return false;
    }

    encCtx->bit_rate = decCtx->bit_rate;
    encCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    encCtx->thread_count = 1;
    encCtx->width = decCtx->width;
    encCtx->height = decCtx->height;

    int fps = fmtc->streams[iVideoStream]->r_frame_rate.num / fmtc->streams[iVideoStream]->r_frame_rate.den;
    encCtx->time_base = (AVRational){1, fps};
    encCtx->framerate = (AVRational){fps, 1};

    encCtx->gop_size = decCtx->gop_size;
    encCtx->max_b_frames = decCtx->max_b_frames;
    encCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;

    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(fmtc->streams[iVideoStream]->codecpar, encCtx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    ret = avcodec_open2(encCtx, encCodec,  nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(encCtx, source);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    av_packet_unref(pkt);
    av_init_packet(pkt);

    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(encCtx, pkt);
    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
        return false;
    else if (ret < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ret >= 0)
    {
        FILE * outPng = fopen("./sample.png", "wb");
        fwrite(pkt->data, pkt->size, 1, outPng);
        fclose(outPng);
    }
```

What I do wrong with converting image to RGB24 or with encoding it?

Comment: Have you looked at [this example](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/blob/master/0_hello_world.c) yet? The `save_gray_frame` function should apply in your case. You may want to try to decode the packet to a frame and write the frame data to an image instead just like in the example.

Comment: Hmm, you mean manually create a header of png/jpeg file and then write points data directly. This could work, thanks! I will mark your advice as a solution. I will keep it in mind for the future. However we research a little and ffmpeg could correctly write to file if you have originally mpegPng format or something like that. In our case we used opencv cv::Mat to convert AVFrame to proper picture format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@parthlr provided acceptable solution in the discussion above. However, you also can read my comment under his preposition.